Seemingly denying an offer is translated as accepting it
I've been trying to practice listening by watching Ghibli's From Up on Poppy Hill. I didn't get very far. Within the first few minutes, an older lady is offered a tea and answers:

いいえ、済ませてきたから。

As the beginner I still am, I felt like this was obviously turning down the offer — she literally said "no". Google Translate is also seemingly confused and translated it as "No, I've already finished it." Nonetheless, the tea is served, so I checked the English dub, and there it's translated with something like "Yes, that would be nice."
Assuming this might be something like a proverb or a common saying, I googled the phrase in varying combinations, but I couldn't find anything. I'd be grateful for some insight on how "no" means "yes" in this special case.

First of all, she said いいよ, not いいえ. But いいよ in a context like this means not "That would be nice" but "No thank you". So the grandma clearly turned down something by saying "No thanks, I've already finished it". As far as pure Japanese interpretation goes, that's all that can be said.
Actually, the exchange between the girl and her grandmother in this scene appears quite confusing even for Japanese people (myself included), and many people have asked about this scene on the net, including this one. I read more than five such questions but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. It might be related to customs or rules specific to this family, but I believe it's difficult to explain this scene with the general knowledge about the Showa-era culture.
In the English translation, the translator probably chose to use "That would be nice" to avoid confusing the audience. This kind of adaptation is often done in professional translation, so from a language learning perspective, it's best not to worry about it too much.

Ya, in the profession, there's "translation", which is turning the words from Language A into corresponding words in Language B.  And then there's "localization", which is more about the intent and what fits socially and culturally.  Sounds like the English dub opted to localize instead of translate -- and, as naruto says above, this is probably the correct move for this particularly confusing scene.

I can definitely imagine English works in which someone says something like "oh, no, I wouldn't want to bother you" and the listener takes it as a yes. Of course, subtitles don't get to benefit from tone or other cues.
